# How do you find the rolling min() or max() index values over a certain window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently running Python 3.7.4 and somewhat new to Python programming.  I have time series data of a stocks Close Price.  I'm using the 'rolling' function to create a new column within my dataframe to calculate a rolling minimum and maximum spread (i.e., the range) over a 60 day period.

```
df['max'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).max()
df['min'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).min()
df['range'] = df['max'] - df['min']
```

What I am having trouble with is knowing whether the minimum value occurred first or the maximum value occurred first within the 60 day window. I would like to create a new column within the dataframe that gives me a flag telling me if the min or max occurred first (e.g., if min index values is < max index value over the rolling 60 day period, `df['flag'] = 1; else df['flag'] = -1`.

I'm using this as a simple way to tell if the stock price has moved up or down over each rolling period.

I tried using an 'if' statement but ran into some issues given the "truth value of an array with more than one element" error:

```
if df['Close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).max().index.values > df['Close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).max().index.values:
    df['flag'] = 1
else:
    df['flag'] = -1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would recommend doing a `.where` on values for the rolling min and max and then comparing the indexes to find which one came first :)

Comment: Should it be something like this? 'df['flag'] = np.where(df['Close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).max().index.values > df['Close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).max().index.values, 1, -1)'  when i do this, all the values are coming up -1.

Comment: It appears to be setting each row equal to the index value for all rows (e.g., for index row 2, min index value is 2 and max index value is 2, so 2 is not less than 2 and the flag value is -1)